# How do I Show/Hide (Toggle) DIV on click anywhere on the page

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I am making a portfolio website, and the pictures are full screen in the background and I used z-index to place a transparent div with text above it. I would like to toggle the DIV with the fonts visibility just by clicking anywhere on the page. And if possible, have it with a fade-in and fade-out function.

I am still new to jQuery, so any help would be wonderful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
// dom ready
$(function(){

    // body click
    $("body").click(function(){

        // element to toggle
        var $el = $(".your-element");

        // toggle div
        if ($el.is(":visible")) {
            // fade out
            $el.fadeOut(200);
        } else {
            // fade in
            $el.fadeIn(200);                
        }

    });
});
```

jQuery methods used:
[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)
[.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)
[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here. 

I tried using it and it didn't work. But I may be implementing it wrong. 

Since i'm only using one page with no other links i'm putting the code into the HTML file instead of another JS file. As well where the ".your-element" is i'm putting in the div name which is "#Title"

I'm a good two days new to jQuery so hope you understand. Learning as i'm going. lol.

Comment: Im pretty sure this code works. Have you included the jQuery library?  Note that the library must be included before this script. Here is how you include the library: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: ... or maybe you have some other javascript error? Check your console: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Comment: hahah, oh lord. I forgot the dang library. Givin' it a shot now. Fail me. 

In my defense i've been up for way to long.